# Sharepoint 2010 custom workflow action

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a custom workflow action using visual studio and created a list workflow with the custom action.

When i start the workflow its running till the custom action and the workflow gives error like this "error 'workflow name'".

No furthur error information and i couldn't figure out what is the problem.

what could be the problem or how i debug ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can see further info in ULS log.
Use this tool https://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Super!!!. Thank you.. I found the exact message using ULS log viewer.